# Columns generated by wprintf are not equal

Tags: c, indentation, wchar-t

I'm using wprintf to print out c-strings of different size.

```
wprintf(L"%-*.*ls ", PRINTED_WORD_LENGTH, PRINTED_WORD_LENGTH, word->string);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < word->usage_length; i++) {
    printf("%d ", word->usage[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

As you can see, these strings contain some diacritic characters. Rows with these characters aren't formatted correctly (wprintf doesn't use enough spaces when it encounters them). Is there any way to format rows correctly without writing a new function?

```
z                                39 46 62 113 
za                               101 105 
zabawa                           132 
zasną                           123 
zatrzymać                       88
```

Comment: wprintf() followed by printf() without an intervening fwide() or freopen() call is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They *align* correctly at the byte level. Only because you are looking at it as UTF-8 multi-byte characters make you feel they are not correctly *aligned* (for whatever definition of text alignment you want to use.)

If you are targeting a POSIX-conforming implementation, you can perhaps use the [wcswidth(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/wcswidth.html) function: it was purposely specified to solve this kind of problems (originally with CJKV characters.) It is a bit lower-level though.